# Strategy for coating a built table with polyurethane?

Tags: finishing, technique, polyurethane

I built a simple table. I stained each piece before final gluing and construction.

I am not sure how to polyurethane the table.  I am concerned about both getting an even coat that doesn't run and how to coat the entire thing at once (do I skip the bottom of the feet?)

Should I do different sections at a time?  All at once?  Brush on the top and spray on the legs?  Brush everywhere?

[image: The Table in Question]

Comment: Really any of these will work.  If your biggest concern is runs (and you don't mind taking longer) you can use "wiping" poly.  Just mix oil-based poly 50/50 with mineral spirits and wipe it on with a folded up paper towel.  It'll take more coats but it's a lot more forgiving than brushing or spraying.

Comment: That's a nice looking table. To avoid getting poly on the feet, use mask it with painter's tape.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232, that's an Answer right there. I'll +1 it if you add it. Wiping varnish is the best solution very often and as we head into colder weather it has even more to recommend it. Might be worth mentioning that dilution of only 1/3 extra MS can be enough to get the effect one wants.

Comment: Hi Joshua, welcome to Woodworking. It sounds like you could do with reading any decent finishing book for beginners/learners, I can recommend anything by Bob Flexner or Michael Dresdner, and there are others worth reading. One of the best ground-up books is **Wood Finishing 101** by Flexner. If you don't want to buy it sight-unseen check any local libraries, they could well have a copy.